# How to resize image before upload and store in database in codeingiter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file, upload

Here is my code from controller

`

$type= explode('.', $_FILES['picture']['name']);

```
                        $type = $type[count($type)-1];



                        $url = "uploads/products/images/".uniqid(rand()).".".$type;

                        if(in_array($type, array('jpg','jpeg','png','JPG','JPGE','PNG') ) )
                        {
                            if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']))
                            {
                               move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'],$url);
                            }
                        }
                        '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using CodeIgniter, it has it's own Image Manipulation class:

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['source_image'] = '/path/to/image/mypic.jpg';
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']         = 75;
$config['height']       = 50;

$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Set the width and height variables to what you need to resize the image to.

Comment: $url = "uploads/products/images/".uniqid(rand()).".".$type;
 Here I'm passing destination_folder/image_name.image_type this could be folder/mypic.jpg.  how can I resize image in this format?  only value of $url stored in database.